# Are there ways to view the small Facebook profile pictures by just knowing the email id?

Tags: php, facebook

Can we read the profile picture by giving the email id? I have some email addresses, and I want to put them on my web page. Can it show the Facebook profile picture if the user has Facebook account with that email id?

Answer (score 2):

No.  You need the facebook user id.

See the [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user).